# How to debug AsyncTask and its methods after progress dialog is running in Mobile app?

Tags: android

I am new to Android Development. I am setting a debugger points in a code and trying to check how JSON results are present inside doInbackground and `postexecute()` method by using `AsyncTask()`.

I am unable to do debugging since it is coming out of the window after `preExecute()` completes.

Even in real time, the app is not getting crashed, after progress dialog bar got dismissed, it is taking me to Home page.

I need to debug even doInbackground and postExecute() method. What mistake could I have done here?

```
new MakeRequestAndResponse().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, edtPhone,
                edtPass, "android", gcmToken, version, mAndroidId);

class MakeRequestAndResponse extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    private ProgressDialog pr;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pr = new ProgressDialog(Activity_Login.this);
        s = new SpannableString("Verifying credentials..");
        s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(Activity_Login.this, "Lato-Regular.ttf"), 0, s.length(),
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        pr.setMessage(s);
        pr.setIndeterminate(false);
        pr.setCancelable(false);
        pr.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... param) {
        JSONObject jsonObj = null;
        try {

            try {
                jsonObj = makeRequest(param[0], param[1], param[2], param[3], param[4], param[5]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            if (jsonObj == null) {
                return "null response";
            } else {
                return jsonObj.toString();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "null response";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String json) {

        if (pr.isShowing() && pr != null) {
            pr.dismiss();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, json);
        System.out.println("Login Json Response:"+json);
```

Comment: Just try to hide/comment `pr.show();` from `onPreExecute` method until you finish debugging.

Comment: Okay, I will try to do